# How to use a custom view in main activity

Tags: android, android-view

I'm developing a game which shows shapes randomly, I got the class but I got no idea how to call the custom view from my GameFragment. I was wondering if anyone can help me to achieve it.

**CustomView.java**

```
public class CustomViews extends View {

    private final int SQUARE_SIZE = 500;
    private RectF rectF;
    private Paint paint;
    private boolean CIRCLE = false;
    private boolean RECTANGLE = false;

    public CustomViews(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(null);
    }

    public CustomViews(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomViews(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomViews(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set) {

        rectF = new RectF();
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        randomColorGenerator();
    }

    public void rect(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        int width = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        rectF.set(width - 200, height - 200, width + 200, height + 200);
    }

    private void circle(Canvas canvas) {

        float cx;
        float cy;
        float radius = 200;

        cx = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        cy = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);

    }

    private void randomColorGenerator() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int choices = 3;

        switch (random.nextInt(choices)) {
            case 0:
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case 1:
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 2:
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void randomShapeGenerator(Canvas canvas) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int numberOfMethods = 2;

        switch (random.nextInt(numberOfMethods)) {
            case 0:
                rect(canvas);
                rectSelected();
                break;
            case 1:
                circle(canvas);
                circleSelected();
                break;

        }
    }

    public boolean circleSelected(){
        RECTANGLE = false;
        return CIRCLE = true;
    }

     public boolean rectSelected( ) {
        CIRCLE = false;
        return RECTANGLE = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        randomShapeGenerator(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(rectF, paint);
    }
}
```

Now I need to call it from my GameFragment where there are some buttons and whenever you click on them a new random shape must be generate. Is anyone got any idea?

Comment: any feedback after the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your fragment has a `LinearLayout` with id `main_content` then this might help you to add your custom view programmatically:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        LinearLayout main_layout = findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        CustomViews customView = new CustomViews(this);
        customView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        main_layout.addView(customView);
    });
```

layoutParams might be also tuned according your needs.

You have to take into account where you want to display the customViews and also their sizes. For instance, if you have a linear layout with `vertical` orientation, you can add views in the following way:

```
main_layout.addView(customView, 400, 400);
```

This will display multiple customViews one below the other (until the screen's height is reached).
Indeed, `CustomViews` has to be modified a bit (here are two methods to be changed):

```
public void rect(Canvas canvas) {
      int height = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
      int width = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
      rectF.set(width - 200, height - 200, width + 200, height + 200);
      canvas.drawRect(rectF, paint);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     randomShapeGenerator(canvas);
}
```

Comment: yeah it works but only once ! I mean the second time and more you click on button nothing happens ,